# How to resolve "module not found" in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, web-development-server

When I compile my app, it shows the error:

```
./src/Components/Landing.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\Users\gaura\Documents\REACT\love-writing\src\Components'
```

Following is the code of App.js and I have created a component named as Landing.js which is a fucntional component.

**

- App.js

**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Landing from './Components/Landing';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Landing/>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**

- Landing.js

**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Landing = () => {
    const Accesstoken = window.localStorage.token;
    return(
        <div className = "App">
            <div className = "intro-message">
                <h1>Love Writing</h1>
                <br>
                </br>
                <h2>Makes your writing easier and better</h2>
                <hr className = "intro-divider" />
            </div>
            <div className="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
        <div className="list-inline-item">
          {!Accesstoken ? (
            <div>
              <Link to="/login">
                <button className="network-name">LOG IN</button>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/register">
                <button className="network-name">SIGN UP</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Link to="/addcategory">
                <button className="network-name">ADD GENRES</button>
              </Link>

              <Link to="/categories">
                <button className="network-name">VIEW GENRES</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
            )}

        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="copyright">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Love_Writing_Neha_Chaudhary 2019. All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Landing;
```

**

- Project Structure

** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXvMp.jpg

I have properly imported Landing.js in App.js. I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Did you installed react-router-dom package? npm i react-router-dom

Comment: haha, you just need to install that package, it's obvious

Comment: The error was different. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try by installing router-dom package by running the following in Shell/CMD

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Found the real culprit:

You have not used `<Link />` inside the Router. You should wrap `<Landing />` component in the router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <Landing />
</Router>
```

The `<Link />` component is not allowed to use outside the Router scope.

**You may skip reading the following sections.**

It seems you have not the package installed in your node_modules. So, run this command:

```
npm install react-router
```

It will install the `react-router` which holds the `react-router-dom` along with it.

If you are developing your app for browser only, then you may only install the react-router-dom:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

I'm not fully sure what's going on there, so you may try this:

```
npm install react-router react-router-dom
```

Or, you might have compromised npm_modules? Run this command:

```
npm install
```

---

Wait! From your error, it seems you have not run project correctly. It should show you the file path from server. But it's showing you file path from the system? Run this command to start the project:

```
npm start
```

---

And if still doesn't help you. Here's my final thought:

```
rm -rf node_modules # remove all packages
npm cache clean # clear the cache
npm install # install all the packages
npm install --save react-router # if react-router-dom isn't in your package.json
npm start # run the project
# project should be run in localhost:3000 by default.
```

Comment: the related package is react-router-dom

Comment: After doing what you just told, I'm getting this error.

Comment: ./src/Components/Landing.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\Users\gaura\Documents\REACT\love-writing\src\Components'

Comment: @NehaChaudhary just install react-router-dom package as I indicated in the comment with this command   npm i react-router-dom

Comment: I did npm i react-router-dom... Still getting error like

Comment: You should not use <Link>

Comment: No, you need to install react-router. Read my edited answer again.

Comment: I have found the bug in your code. And updated my answer along with it.